# Compute the number of overlapping time intervals for a binned reporting period elegantly using Python/Pandas/...?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with events that each have a start and end date.  I also have a reporting period with a start and end date and a reporting frequency, e.g. monthly.  What I want to calculate is the number of "active" events in each reporting period bin.  An active event is an event for which the time overlaps with the time interval of the reporting period bin.

After struggling to much with DataFrame aggregation functions, I have come up with the following code that does the job but which is far from compact and elegant.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to write this more compactly but need some leads.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# Example DF of events each with a start and end date provided as a string (my input data)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','start','end'], index=range(7), \
                  data=[[1,'2006-01-01','2007-10-01'],
                        [2,'2007-10-02','2008-12-01'],
                        [3,'2010-01-15','2010-10-20'],
                        [4,'2009-04-04','2010-06-03'],
                        [5,'2010-05-12','2010-08-31'],
                        [6,'2016-05-12','2199-12-31'],                       
                        [7,'2016-05-12','2199-12-31']])

# Reporting period in which we want to calculate the number of "ongoing"/"active" events:
reporting_period_start = '2010-01-01'
reporting_period_end   = '2011-01-01'
reporting_freq         = 'MS'

print('Input data:')
print(df)

# Convert the string dates to timestamps
def to_timestamp(str):
    return pd.Timestamp(str)
df.start = df.start.apply(to_timestamp)
df.end   = df.end.apply(to_timestamp)

# Create an additional colmun in the dataframe to capture the event time interval as an pandas.Interval 
# pandas.Intervals offer a since .overlaps() function
def to_interval(s, e):
    return pd.Interval(s, e)
df['interval'] = df.apply(lambda row: to_interval(row.start, row.end), axis=1)

# Create a data range and a period range to create reporting intervals (e.g. monthly)
# for which we want to count the number of event intervals that overlap with the reporting interval.
bins = pd.date_range(reporting_period_start, reporting_period_end, freq=reporting_freq)
print(bins)

# Convert the date ranges into a list of reporting intervals
# This is ugly code that most probably can be writting a lot more elegantly
intervals = []
n = bins.values.shape[0]
i = 0;
for b in bins[:-1]:
    intervals.append(pd.Interval(pd.to_datetime(bins.values[i]), pd.to_datetime(bins.values[(i+1)%n]), closed='right'))
    i = i + 1

# Function for trying a pandas.Dataframe.apply / resample / groupby or something alike...
def overlaps(i1, i2):
    try:
        return i1.overlaps(i2)
    except:
        return None

result_list = np.zeros(len(intervals)).astype(int)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    j = 0
    for interval in intervals:
        result_list[j] = result_list[j]+overlaps(intervals[j], row.interval)
        j = j + 1

print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you think of your intervals as step functions, which have a value of 1 for the duration of the interval, and 0 otherwise then this can be concisely solved with [staircase](https://www.staircase.dev) which has been built upon `pandas` and `numpy` for analysis with step functions.

In this setup code I have changing the dates in year 2199 to be None to indicate the end time is not known.  I'm assuming that's what you may have wanted.  If this is not correct then don't make this change.

**setup**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Example DF of events each with a start and end date provided as a string   
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['id','start','end'],
    index=range(7),
    data=[[1,'2006-01-01','2007-10-01'],
          [2,'2007-10-02','2008-12-01'],
          [3,'2010-01-15','2010-10-20'],
          [4,'2009-04-04','2010-06-03'],
          [5,'2010-05-12','2010-08-31'],
          [6,'2016-05-12',None],                       
          [7,'2016-05-12',None]])


df["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start"])
df["end"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end"])

reporting_period_start = '2010-01-01'
reporting_period_end   = '2011-01-01'
reporting_freq         = 'MS'
```

**solution**

Your intervals do not start and end on month boundaries.  We need to "floor" the start times to month boundaries, and "ceiling" the end times to month boundaries, to make sure that intervals that overlap a month overlap each other too.  To my knowledge, there is currently no elegant way to do this, but the following will work

```
df["start"] = df["start"].dt.to_period("M").dt.to_timestamp()
df["end"] = (df["end"].dt.to_period("M")+1).dt.to_timestamp()
```

`df` now looks like this

```
   id      start        end
0   1 2006-01-01 2007-11-01
1   2 2007-10-01 2009-01-01
2   3 2010-01-01 2010-11-01
3   4 2009-04-01 2010-07-01
4   5 2010-05-01 2010-09-01
5   6 2016-05-01        NaT
6   7 2016-05-01        NaT
```

Now we create a step function which is the combination of all intervals.  When an interval starts the step function value increases by 1.  When an interval finishes the value decreases by 1. So the value of the step function at any point will be the number of intervals overlapping that point. A step function is represented by the [staircase.Stairs class](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/reference/Stairs.html). This class is to `staircase` as `Series` is to `pandas`.

```
import staircase as sc

stepfunction = sc.Stairs(df, "start", "end")
```

There are many things you can do with step functions in staircase including plotting.

```
stepfunction.plot(style="hlines")
```

[image: step function plot]

Since the intervals now start and end at month boundaries, and the bins are month boundaries we can answer your question by finding the maximum value of the step function for each month.

```
bins = pd.date_range(reporting_period_start, reporting_period_end, freq=reporting_freq)
result = stepfunction.slice(bins).max()
```

`result` will be a `pandas.Series` indexed by a monthly interval index, whose values are the number of intervals overlapping with that month

```
[2010-01-01, 2010-02-01)    2.0
[2010-02-01, 2010-03-01)    2.0
[2010-03-01, 2010-04-01)    2.0
[2010-04-01, 2010-05-01)    2.0
[2010-05-01, 2010-06-01)    3.0
[2010-06-01, 2010-07-01)    3.0
[2010-07-01, 2010-08-01)    2.0
[2010-08-01, 2010-09-01)    2.0
[2010-09-01, 2010-10-01)    1.0
[2010-10-01, 2010-11-01)    1.0
[2010-11-01, 2010-12-01)    0.0
[2010-12-01, 2011-01-01)    0.0
dtype: float64
```

*To recap, the solution (after imports and setup) is*

```
df["start"] = df["start"].dt.to_period("M").dt.to_timestamp()
df["end"] = (df["end"].dt.to_period("M")+1).dt.to_timestamp()
result = sc.Stairs(df, "start", "end").slice(bins).max()
```

**note:** I am the creator of staircase. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: Just great solution, thanks for the effort.